# In namespaced api (Api::V1) I can't access serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, serialization

`Api::V1` is the namespacing of my `schedules#index` resource. But the controller won't access the serializer.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiController < ApplicationController
      include ActionController::Serialization
      include Concerns::ErrorHandler

      before_action do
        namespace_for_serializer = Api::V1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SchedulesController < ApiController

      def index
        @schedules = current_user.schedules
        render json: @schedules
      end

    end
  end
end
```

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ScheduleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried everything. Declare the serializer directly vs `each_serializer: ScheduleSerializer` which just returns an "uninitialized constant" error.

What am I missing?

Comment: It will be a constant autoloading problem. Where's your serializer located?

Comment: @igneus `app/serializers/api/v1/schedule_serializer.rb`

Comment: Have you tried to reference the fully qualified name `each_serializer: Api::V1::ScheduleSerializer` ?